# How to get a MS Translator access token from Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, security, web, oauth-2.0

I am trying to work with a MS Translator API from Swift 3 (right now playing in playgrounds, but the target platform is iOS). However, I got stuck when I was trying to get an access token for OAuth2. I have following code (I tried to port the code from example at [Obtaining an access token](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh454950.aspx)):

```
let clientId = "id".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!
let clientSecret = "secret".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!
let scope = "http://api.microsofttranslator.com".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!

let translatorAccessURI = "https://datamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/OAuth2-13"
let requestDetails = "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=\(clientId)&client_secret=\(clientSecret)&scope=\(scope)"

let postData = requestDetails.data(using: .ascii)!
let postLength = postData.count

var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: translatorAccessURI)!)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.setValue("\(postLength)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")

request.httpBody = postData

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: webRequest) { (returnedData, response, error) in
    let data = String(data: returnedData!, encoding: .ascii)
    print(data)
    print("**************")
    print(response)
    print("**************")
    print(error)
}.resume()
```

Of course, I used a valid clientId and a valid clientSecret.

Now the callback prints following information. First, the returnedData contain a message that the request was invalid, along with a following message:

```
"ACS90004: The request is not properly formatted."
```

Second, the response comes with a 400 code (which fits the fact that the request is not properly formatted).

Third, the error is nil.

Now I was testing the call using Postman, and when I used the same URI, and put the requestDetails string as a raw body message (I added the `Content-Type` header manually), I got the same response. However, when I changed the body type in Postman UI to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and typed in the request details as key value pairs through its UI, the call succeeded. Now it seems that I am doing something wrong with the message formatting, or maybe even something bad with the Swift URLRequest/URLSession API, however, I cannot get a hold on to what. Can somebody help me out, please? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so after some more desperate googling and experimenting I have found my error. For the future generations:

The problem resided in encoding the parameters in the body of the PUT http request. Instead of:

```
let scope = "http://api.microsofttranslator.com"
             .addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!
```

I have to use the following:

```
let scope = "http://api.microsofttranslator.com"
             .addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: 
                         CharacterSet(charactersIn: ";/?:@&=$+{}<>,").inverted)!
```

Seems that the API (or the HTTP protocol, I am not an expert in this) have problems with `/` and `:` characters in the request body. I have to give credit to Studiosus' answer on [Polyglot issue report](https://github.com/ayanonagon/Polyglot/issues/10).